# Excel Userform - check if cell is empty then

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, userform

I'm trying to make a userform where after someone clicks the button, it first checks that specified cells are empty.

If they already have values in them then I want to display a message box to the user. If they are empty then I'll proceed to fill them in. For some reason whenever I run the userform, it displays the message box that the cells are not empty but then continues to fill them in anyways. I'm not sure if I'm using the if statement incorrectly or something.

here's the code starting after i've declared the variable (BtwCells) from the userform text box inputs:

```
If IsEmpty(BtwCells.Value) = False Then

MsgBox ("Error - overlapping reservations")

End If

BtwCells.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
BtwCells.Value = Application.username & "/" & Me.TBNotes.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: `IsEmpty` won't work if `BtwCells` is more than one cell. Use `Application.CountA` and check if the result > 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code as is - there is a logical error with your `If...Then` Statement.

The statement is executed and **whether your `MsgBox` displays or not**, the code will continue to:

```
BtwCells.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
BtwCells.Value = Application.username & "/" & Me.TBNotes.Value
```

You need to tell the code within the `If...Then` block to `Exit Sub` which will abort the code and prevent anything below that line from executing.

```
If IsEmpty(BtwCells.Value) = False Then

    MsgBox ("Error - overlapping reservations")
    Exit Sub  'This will abort the code below this line from executing.

End If

BtwCells.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
BtwCells.Value = Application.username & "/" & Me.TBNotes.Value
End Sub
```